# A small variation of the Magic square problem

Tags: combinatorics

Let us consider a $n \times n$ grid squares. We put numbers from $0$ to $n^{2}$ ( note that you can omit any one number from $0$ to $n^{2}$ ) such that sum of elements in each row ,each column and each longest diagonal is same. Now the question is, whenever such an arrangement is possible, what is the maximum and minimum value of that sum?

My try: For a $1 \times 1$ grid, it is trivial. Now, it can easily be seen that for a $2 \times 2$ grid, there can be no such arrangement possible.

Now we can prove that for any $n$, whenever the arrangement exists, the number which we omit must be divisible by $n$. We denote the sum by $S$ and the omitted number as $m$. Then we must have(considering the $n$ rows),

$$ nS + m=0 + 1 + 2 + \cdots + n^2 = n \left(\dfrac{n (n^{2} + 1)}{2}\right) $$

which shows $n|m$. Thus we may write $m=nk$ for some $k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1,n\}$. Thus from the above expression we can see that $\max S \leq \frac{n(n^{2}+1)}{2}$(when $k=0$) and $\min S \geq \frac{n(n^{2}-1)}{2}$(when $k=n$). Now, when we omit $0$, we are actually finding magic squares of order $n$ which exists $\forall n \geq 3$(though I do not know why this holds when $n$ is even). Hence we have $\max S = \frac {n(n^{2}+1)}{2}$. The problem now remains to find ${\rm min} \space S$.

Comment: The max sum is when you use 1 to $n^2$. The min sum is when you use 0 to $n^2-1$

Comment: The max sum is (n+1)(2n+1)/6. The min sum is... err... I cant calculate it now. Also, I thought 0+1+2...n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6?

Comment: @jonnytan999, how can you say that the minimum sum will be obtained when we use $0$ to $n^{2}-1$?

Comment: We can only use 0 to n^2, so the minimum sum can  be taken by using the smallest n^2 numbers. Also, 1 to n^2 should work for all squares, so subtracting one from each number will also use 0 to $n^2-1$

Answer (score 1):

The minimum sum will be, if you omit the number $n^2$. Then you can build a square with the numbers from 0 to $n^2-1$. Every summand will be 1 smaller. Thus the sum of a row/column/diagonal will be n smaller and equal to $\frac{n^2\cdot (n^2-n)}{2}$. This is the result you already have.

Now I am not sure, what your problem is.